# Select element which contains a specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some nested elements and my HTML structure doesn't has any discipline. Also there is not any classname or id for selecting element considered. So, the only clue that I have is containing specific element.

**Note:** It should be noted, my HTML codes are dynamic. I mean is their structure is not identical all the time. Sometimes they are like this:

```
<div> <h1> <span> anything </span> </h1> <h5> anything> </h5> </div>
```

And sometimes else they are like this:

```
<div> anything </div> <div> <h2> anything </h2> <h5> anything> </h5> </div>
```

And sometimes else they are like this:

```
<div> <span> anything </span> </div> <div> <h5> anything> <h2> anything </h2> </h5> </div>
```

And so on ..! Well, As you see, I can not use none of these:

- `$(elmnt).closest("tag");`
- `$(elmnt).siblings("tag");`

Because as I said, the HTML code is not constant. Now I want to know, How can I select that `<div>` which is containing `<h5>`? So I want this output for three examples above:

```
<div> <h1> <span> anything </span> </h1> <h5> anything> </h5> </div>

<div> <h2> anything </h2> <h5> anything> </h5> </div>

<div> <h5> anything> <h2> anything </h2> </h5> </div>
```

Well, how can I do that?

Comment: `$('div:has(> h5)')` is it?

Comment: $('h5').parent() ? that?

Comment: `$($('h5').parents('div')[0])` will select the any div that contains a h5 even if there is something between

Comment: @Jai sounds good. I will check it. thanks.

Comment: I am also suggesting this, $('h5').closest("div").css('background','#ccc');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:has(selector)`, `.has()` or `.filter()` would give you that div:

using `:has()`:

```
$('div:has(> h5)')
```

```js
$('div:has(> h5)').css('background', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> <h1> <span> anything </span> </h1> <h5> anything </h5> </div>
```

using `.has()`:

```
$('div').has('> h5)')
```

```js
$('div').has('> h5').css('background', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> <h1> <span> anything </span> </h1> <h5> anything </h5> </div>
```

using `.filter()`:

```
$('div').filter(function(){
    return $(this).children('h5').length !== 0 
});
```

```js
$('div').filter(function(){
    return $(this).children('h5').length !== 0
}).css('background', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> <h1> <span> anything </span> </h1> <h5> anything </h5> </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can select heading with h5 like this.

```
jQuery("div > h5").parent()
```

Comment: _How can I select that <div> which is containing <h5>?_, this doesnot select the div.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
 $('div h5').parent()
```

I'm not sure about the parent() function, but there should be something similar available....

Answer (score 1):

You can get the div, with the parent() selector:

Check only the div, with containt a h5 element :
If the direct parent of the `<h5>` element isn't a "div", the selector doesn't select the parent:

```
 $("div > h5").parent();

<div><h5>Something</h5></div>
```

Or if you want to get the parent (not direct) of the div element, you can use :

```
$("h5").parent("div");

<!-- In this case: the selected parent element is the <div></div> -->
<div><p><h5>Something</h5></p></div>
```

If you want to get the parent (if the parent is not a div) you can just use :

```
$("h5").parent();

<!-- In this case: the parent element is the <p></p> -->
<div><p><h5>Something</h5></p></div>
```

you have the official JQuery documentation here => https://api.jquery.com/parent/